# Can FTSearch(Domino API) find mails sent between a particular hour or minutes

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Could someone please let me know whether it possible to find mails sent between a particular hour or minutes using FTSearch(Domino API).

For example, 
If a mail is sent from A to B at 5/27/2011 10:30, can we create a query for FTSearch to find out this mail wherein I give a query like between (5/27/2011 00:00 and 5/27/2011 13:45)

Does the Hour field and Minutes field have any effect on the FTSearch query?
My application is coded in JAVA.

Comment: Ken was faster, so just a link to the documentation for [using operators in the search query](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.notes85.help.doc/sch_refine_query_r.html) because it is somewhat hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the FTSearch method can do that for you.  Your query would look like this:

```
query = "[PostedDate] >= 5/27/2011 AND [PostedDate] < 5/28/2011"
```

Unfortunately it seems there's no way to specify times in the query, just dates.

Comment: Though once you have that document collection, you could remove messages that don't have the right time stamps, right?